# Input type text as formatted date with slashes

Tags: html

How can I mask input type "text" to look like date?
I want it to be formatted as `dd-mm-yyyy`, and that it will add slashes whenever you reach the correct place, so if I type 30111970, it will automatically insert slashed in the corresponding places (as you type):

```
30/11/1970
```

I am using pattern currently, but I don't know how to add the slashes. This is my pattern for `dd-mm-yyyy` format:

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using input type="date"?

Comment: You can't change the format

Answer (score 3):

With HTML5 you could simply use the date input type:

```
<input type="date" name="somename" id="someid">
```

Or if you want manual input you can try following you have to execute a key up function:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="date"
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        var regex=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if (!v.match(regex))
        {
             alert('Must input date or number');
             return false;
        }
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
       }"
    maxlength="10"
>
```

Comment: I know, but you can't format input type date, and I want it to be dd-mm-yyyy, and when you use date, it formats it with regard to the browser

Comment: voted up, this is nearly perfect, but how do I combine this with my pattern? Or at least, how to allow only numbers, so if I try to input characters, it will not show up

Comment: You can also validate characters too. I have updated my answer again.

Comment: I am doing validation on the backend,  but I want a good UI as well.
Btw I think you meant if `if (v.match(regex))` without `!`. Though this piece of code broke the script, but never mind
`

Comment: Another thing: After you write the date once, so you can't change it, because slashes will not re - appear